# Finding highest probability value with sparse_categorical_crossentropy model in Python and Keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I have a keras model trained from a list of tokenized and padded short sentences, associated with a label (integer 0 to 8).

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(length_seq ,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_padded , training_labels, epochs=1000, verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

Assuming I am testing my model with a test sentence

```
test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(['How are you today?'])
padded_test = pad_sequences(test, padding='post', maxlen = length_seq)
label_prob = model.predict(padded_test)
print(label_prob)
predicted_class = label_prob.argmax(axis=-1)
print(predicted_class)
```

The above code would print

```
[[9.9800879e-01 1.6465491e-12 1.9908682e-03 2.6586076e-07 7.0560112e-12
8.8631219e-28 6.8575331e-31 9.3628820e-08 8.5419593e-16]]
[0]
```

The predicted label is `0`, which is accurate, but I am also interested in finding the highest probably value associated with the label in order to make sure it is above a certain threshold for my predictions.

How can I retrieve value `9.9800879e-01`?

Comment: have you tried label_prob.max(axis=-1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marco for the answer:

```
 label_prob.max(axis=-1)
```